# jQuery: how to get the text from a page?

Tags: jquery, text

I need to extract the text (only plain text) from an arbitrary web page (I do bypass the cross-domain problem with a simple php proxy on my server).
I do, as usual,

```
$.get(url, function(data) {
  process(data);
});
```

and, in my process() function I have the content of the page.
I want to consider a particular div (here '#my-div') in that page, or, if not present - as a fallback - the whole body.

I would like to do something like this:

```
function process(content) {
  if ($(content).find('#my-div'))
    $('#output').text($(content).find('#my-div').text());
  else
    $('#output').text($(content).find('body').text());
}
```

But I always bet get an empty result when "finding" 'body': any suggestion?

Comment: If you print the entire variable of content what does it contain? Does it have a body tag?

Comment: I faced this problem before. In my case the response('content') was not properly xml-formatted; check the error console(firebug/firefox)...

Comment: The entire variable contains the full body of the page, with included the html tags, which I want to ignore...

Comment: On firebug console there is only an error like this: $(content).find('body').text is not a function ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues...

```
function process(content) {
   // The if() will always be true, because a jQuery object is always retruend
  if ($(content).find('#my-div'))
    $('#output') = $(content).find('#my-div').text();   // invalid assignment
  else
    $('#output') = $(content).find('body').text();      // invalid assignment
}
```

Fixed...

```
function process(content) {
  var nodes = $(content);  // cache the elements
  if (nodes.find('#my-div').length)
    $('#output').text(nodes.find('#my-div').text());  
  else
    $('#output').text(nodes.find('body').text());     
}
```

---

Now **theoretically** it would seem to work, but there are issues with passing an entire HTML document to the `$` function. You'll find that some browsers strip out some of the elements, like `<head>` and `<body>`.

You'll ultimately need to test for each of these situations, something like this...

```
function process(content) {
  var nodes = $(content);  // cache the elements
  var my_div = nodes.find('#my-div');  // try to get nested #my-div

  if( !my_div.length ) {
      my_div = nodes.filter('#my-div'); // try to get #my-div at top level

      if( !my_div.length ) {
          my_div = nodes.find('body')   // try to get nested body

          if( !my_div.length ) {
              my_div = nodes;  // assume the body content is at the top level
          }
      }
  }
  $('#output').text(my_div.text());   
}
```

Comment: I was going to point out what you said in your last paragraph. I think a solution is to simply do: `content.text()`

Comment: @powerbuoy: That may work. I came up with a longer solution that still tests for the `#my-div` element. I *think* it covers all browsers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm very interested in the second line of your answer: var content = $(content);  // cache the elements
Sorry, I do not fully understand this line; and - how can it be used to cache elements?

Comment: @MarcoS: You're passing an HTML string to jQuery. What happens is that the HTML is parsed and turned into DOM nodes. So when you do `$(content)` 3 times, without saving the result, you're making the browser do triple the work that it would need to do if you just did it *once* and saved the result in a variable.

Comment: @MarcoS: I should have used a different variable name, just as a good practice. I'll update.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
if ($(content).find('#my-div').length)
```

to see if an element exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text property

```
  $('#output').text($(content).find('#my-div').text());
else
  $('#output').text($(content).find('body').text());
```